# Control 220V stepper motor with arduino?

Tags: arduino, stepper-motor

Is that possible?

It is an Saia UFR1 motor running on 220V. 
https://oc.kosmospora.de/index.php/s/gp3szJXgk3P0SMP

Can I simply use a double relais shield?

EDIT:
The motor is part of a valve actuator of my heating at home, so I simply need to move the valve now and then for a few seconds. 
datasheet: https://oc.kosmospora.de/index.php/s/IKvxI8rzKuATTsC

The existing control circuit board is burnt at two places, transistors it seems. Fotos https://ksmspr.uber.space/nextcloud/index.php/s/JwuCxtRpQlVAnWm
Maybe I could try to replace the transistor!?

When I run the motor directly on 220V (one pair, red and yellow wire), it seems it goes a sec CW and then CCW and CW again and so on!?

Comment: Motors intended to run from mains power are going to be very high inductance.  While you can control the rate by synthesizing something slower or a little faster, you won't be able to go a lot faster with a motor wound that way.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the link to the motor data sheet no longer works and it's a repair question anyway.

Answer (score 2):

While a stepper motor is a synchronous motor, the motor you have is meant to be driven by 50/60 Hz @240 volts.

The [datasheet](https://www.agendis-otto.de/files/pdf/johnson/motoren/synchronmotoren/UFR.pdf) clearly shows how to drive it from a relay:

[image]

You could do this from an Arduino with the correct rating relay.

However the motor is not going to operate in a stepping mode where you can control the number of steps using a relay circuit.

Answer (score 1):

Transistor is made by ON Semi and and is something like this.
https://www.digikey.ca/product-detail/en/stmicroelectronics/BUL39D/497-7203-5-ND/1037762.

Transistor fault is secondary.   Root cause unknown.
One track between 1N4005 diodes and and MOV's has separated.
MOV's may be worn out.

It may take some time to find all faulty parts without experience but then I bet distributed raises Honeywell cost by 500%.

Comment: The name "UFR1" indicate it's a 2 coil I'd say!?

Comment: I see now. Male pattern blindness. ')